# Load RAW YUV video in OPENCV

Tags: opencv, yuv

I have a problem with a RAW YUB video load in OpenCV. I can play it in  mplayer with the following command:

```
mplayer myvideo.raw -rawvideo w=1280:h=1024:fps=30:y8 -demuxer rawvideo
```

My code for load in OpenCV is:

```
CvCapture* capture=cvCaptureFromFile("C:\\myvideo.raw");
```

`cvCaptureFromFile` always return NULL. But if I try with a normal avi file, the code runs normally (capture is not null).

I'm working with the lastest version of OpenCV under Windows 7.

EDIT: Output messages are

```
[IMGUTILS @ 0036f724] Picture size 0x0 is invalid  
[image2 @ 009f3300] Could not find codec parameters (Video: rawvideo, yuv420p)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV uses ffmpeg as back-end, however, it includes only a subset of ffmpeg functions. What you can try is to install some codecs. (K-lite helped me some time ago)

But, if your aim is to obtain raw YUV in OpenCV, the answer is "not possible".

OpenCV is hardcoded to convert every input format to BGR, so even if you will be able to open the raw input, it will automatically convery it to BGR before passing it. No chance to solve that, the only way is to use a different capture library or hack into OpenCV.

What you can do (to simulate YUV input) is to capture the avi, convert to YUV

```
cvtColor(...,CV_BGR2YCBCR /* or CV_BGR2YUV */ );
```

and then process it