# Is there a way to access image buffer through OpenCV VideoCapture?

Tags: c++, opencv

Due to some reasons I need to access directly to image buffer from a camera through OpenCV's VideoCapture but I cannot find a way. To make it more clear, I want to access to the data from *cv::VideoCapture::grab()* before retrieving it to a *cv::Mat*.

I check the OpenCV source code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/638a01a014cb1972a6ffa63755474ce89e3db9d8/modules/videoio/src/cap_mjpeg_decoder.cpp)
and it seems OpenCV decodes it automatically before outputing the frame. Intuitionally I am thinking about "encoding" the frame to obtain the original data, however, *cv::imencode* requires a specific file extension.

Is there a way to access the camera buffer data without tweaking the source code?

Best,

Eric

Comment: Have you seen [this answer from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165836/4669135) that seems to say you cannot, and [this answer from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27914179/4669135) that seems related ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I already saw the answer from 2011 but I don't know if it's still not possible right now. I've tried the "VideoCapture.set()" method and it did not work for me. I am developing in Windows and V4L2 should be designed for Linux. The image data from the camera I use is actually a combination data of two cameras in YUY2. If I can access to the image buffer, it would be easy to seperate them.